# Accumulating while in recursion/backtracking

Tags: prolog

I run into this beginners problem, and i don't know how to solve this. Here is my code:

```
worker( w1, d1, 2000 ) .    
worker( w2, d1, 2500 ) .
worker( w2, d2, 1000 ) .
worker( w3, d2, 2000 ) .
worker( w4, d2, 4000 ) .

% worker( W, D, S ) means that worker W works in department D and has salary S

department( d1, w2 ) .
department( d2, w4 ) .

% department( D, B ) means that worker B is director of department D(this is not important in this case)
```

I need to get sum of all salaries form one of department, like this:

```
?- department_costs( d1 , T ) .
T = 4500;
no
?- department_costs( D, T ) .
D = d1
T = 4500;
D = d2
T = 7000;
no
?- department_costs( d3 , T ) .
no
```

I tried this:

```
department_costs( D, T ):- worker( _X, D, T1 ), T is T1.
```

And I get this:

```
?- department_costs( o1, T ).
T=2000;
T=2500;
no
```

now I need to sum T+T for total costs, but I don't know how to do that. I would like to solve this **without** using findall/setof/bagof.

**EDIT:**

I tried with findall:

```
sumL([], 0).
sumL([G|R], S):-
   sumL(R, S1),
   S is S1 + G.

department_costs( D, T ):-
   findall(P, worker( _X, D, P ), R ),
   sumL(R, S),
   T=S.
```

It works fine with department_costs( d1, T ), and department_costs( d2, T ), but when I enter department_costs( D, T ). i get this:

```
 department_costs( D, T ).
 O=_h159
 T=11500
```

and it should be like this:

```
 ?- department_costs( D, T ) .
 D = d1
 T = 4500;
 D = d2
 T = 7000;
```

can someone tell what is the problem now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wanting to solve this without `findall/3` will just result in a poor attempt at recoding said `findall/3`. If you really wanna skip `findall/3`, represent your data in a different way, for example:

```
workers([w1-d1-2000, w2-d1-2500, w2-d2-1000, w3-d2-2000, w4-d2-4000]).
departments([d1-w2, d2-w4]).
```

In this format you will be able to use recursion and list processing techniques to achieve a good result. In the previous one you will have to go with either database manipulation and/or global variables. Not really Prolog-ish.

For your edit, the problem is that you use `findall/3`, and that `findall/3` will give you all the results for the one variable you're interested in, but will not precise the bindings that led to those results.

Try `bagof/3` instead:

```
bagof(S, W^worker( W, D, S ), R ).
```

And see this [man page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.29%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/allsolutions.html%27%29%29) (even if it's SWI, those are ISO Prolog predicates anyway) for more information.

Comment: i'll try then with findall, i'll post my attempt

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer regarding the code you proposed

Comment: @false: to preserve the duplicate salaries if two people have the same salary (which could happen I guess).

Comment: @Mog: That does not make sense: Duplicating a fact in `worker/3` should not have an influence on the outcome! So you need some key that identifies a salary - probably worker+department or contractnr.

Comment: @false: good point. I'll try to fix my answer when I have some minutes : ]

Answer (score 5):

library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)) is meant to solve exactly such kind of problems. It's worth to study.

```
department_costs( D, T ) :- aggregate_all(sum(C), worker( _, D, C ), T).
```

**edit**

XSB has '[Tabling Aggregate Predicates](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~sbprolog/manual1/node77.html)' that should allow you to solve efficiently your problem.

Comment: Ihave to use XSB prolog, I wish there is aggregate library but there isn't :(

Comment: I've seen the SWI-Prolog tag, sorry... XSB should have some more fundamental way to do aggregation, because it implements **tabling**. I'll try to find something in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of crude, and retracts every worker fact used, but will do the trick:

```
department_costs(D,T) :- worker(X,D,T1), retract(worker(X,D,T1)), department_costs(D,T2), T is T1+T2).
department_costs(_,0).
```

A less destructive alternative would be to pass around a list of the workers used so far, verify any worker about to be used isn't in the list, and add the newly-used worker to the list for the recursive call.  (I suppose you could instead just re-assert the retracted fact at the end of the clause, after the recursive call returns, but that feels REALLY hacky.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but the idea is you accumulate the workers you counted already.
I don't really like it though, if I find more than a couple of minutes for this I'm sure you can do it in a more declarative way without the evil cut.

```
department_sum(S, D) :- 
        department_sum_agg([], S, D).

department_sum_agg(Workers, S, D) :- 
    worker(X,D,SX), 
    \+ member(X, Workers), !,
    department_sum_agg([X|Workers], SRest, D),
    S is SX + SRest.

department_sum_agg(_, 0, _).
```

Comment: For query `department_sum(S,D)` the result will depend on the order of answers to `worker/3`. If it is defined with facts, only the department of the first fact will be considered...