# Generate and Test accumulating valid answer for next test

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, data-generation

I know how to do a simple [generate and test](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws0708/logic/prolog9.pdf) to return each answer individually. In the following example only items that are greater than `1` are returned.

```
item(1).
item(1).
item(2).
item(3).
item(1).
item(7).
item(1).
item(4).

gen_test(Item) :-
   item(Item),   % generate
   Item > 1.     % test

?- gen_test(Item).
Item = 2 ;
Item = 3 ;
Item = 7 ;
Item = 4.
```

I can also return the results as a list using [bagof/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3)

```
gen_test_bagof(List) :-
   bagof(Item,(item(Item),Item > 1), List).

?-  gen_test_bagof(List).
List = [2, 3, 7, 4].
```

Now I would like to be able to change the test so that it uses [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) with a list where the list is the accumulation of all previous valid answers.

I have tried this

```
gen_test_acc_facts(L) :-
  gen_test_acc_facts([],L).

gen_test_acc_facts(Acc0,R) :-
  item(H),                          % generate
  (
     member(H,Acc0)                 % test
  ->
    gen_test_acc_facts(Acc0,R)      % Passes test, don't accumulate, run generate and test again.
  ;
    gen_test_acc_facts([H|Acc0],R)  % Fails test, accumulate, run generate and test again.
  ).
```

but since it is recursive, every call of `item/1` results in the same first fact being used.

I suspect the answer will require eliminating backtracking as was done in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907810/1243762) by [mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat) because this needs to **preserve information over backtracking**.

---

**Details**

The example given is a simplified version of the real problem which is to generate graphs with N vertices where the edges are [undirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph), have no 
 [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) (self references), have no [weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Weighted_graph) and the vertexes are [labeled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Properties_of_graphs) and there is no [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooted_graph) vertex and set of graphs is only the [isomorphic graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsomorphicGraphs.html). Generating all of the graphs for N is easy, and while I can accumulate all of the graphs into a list first, then test all of them against each other; once N=8 the memory is exhausted.

```
?- graph_sizes(N,Count).
N = 0, Count = 1 ;
N = Count, Count = 1 ;
N = Count, Count = 2 ;
N = 3, Count = 8 ;
N = 4, Count = 64 ;
N = 5, Count = 1024 ;
N = 6, Count = 32768 ;
N = 7, Count = 2097152 ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

However as there are many redundant isomorphic graphs generated, by pruning the list as it grows, the size of N can be increased. See: [Enumerate all non-isomorphic graphs of a certain size](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29552/268)

---

```
gen_vertices(N,L) :-
  findall(X,between(1,N,X),L).

gen_edges(Vertices, Edges) :-
    findall((X,Y), (member(X, Vertices), member(Y, Vertices), X < Y), Edges).

gen_combination_numerator(N,Numerator) :-
  findall(X,between(0,N,X),L0),
  member(Numerator,L0).

comb(0,_,[]).

comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]) :-
    N>0,
    N1 is N-1,
    comb(N1,T,Comb).

comb(N,[_|T],Comb) :-
    N>0,
    comb(N,T,Comb).

gen_graphs(N,Graph) :-
  gen_vertices(N,Vertices),
  gen_edges(Vertices,Edges),
  length(Edges,Denominator),
  gen_combination_numerator(Denominator,Numerator),
  comb(Numerator,Edges,Graph).

graph_sizes(N,Count) :-
    length(_,N),
    findall(.,gen_graphs(N,_), Sols),
    length(Sols,Count).
```

The [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626677/1243762) for isomorphic graphs in Prolog.

---

Examples of generated graphs:

```
?- gen_graphs(1,G).
G = [] ;
false.

?- gen_graphs(2,G).
G = [] ;
G = [(1, 2)] ;
false.

?- gen_graphs(3,G).
G = [] ;
G = [(1, 2)] ;
G = [(1, 3)] ;
G = [(2, 3)] ;
G = [(1, 2),  (1, 3)] ;
G = [(1, 2),  (2, 3)] ;
G = [(1, 3),  (2, 3)] ;
G = [(1, 2),  (1, 3),  (2, 3)] ;
false.
```

---

The differences between all the graphs being generated ([A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125/list)) vs the [desired](https://oeis.org/A000088/a000088_3.pdf) graphs ([A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349)) .

```
        A006125                             A001349                Extraneous
0       1                                 - 1                    = 0
1       1                                 - 1                    = 0
2       2                                 - 1                    = 1
3       8                                 - 2                    = 6
4       64                                - 6                    = 58
5       1024                              - 21                   = 1003
6       32768                             - 112                  = 32656
7       2097152                           - 853                  = 2096299
8       268435456                         - 11117                = 268424339
9       68719476736                       - 261080               = 68719215656
10      35184372088832                    - 11716571             = 35184360372261
11      36028797018963968                 - 1006700565           = 36028796012263403
12      73786976294838206464              - 164059830476         = 73786976130778375988
13      302231454903657293676544          - 50335907869219       = 302231454853321385807325
14      2475880078570760549798248448      - 29003487462848061    = 2475880078541757062335400387    
15      40564819207303340847894502572032  - 31397381142761241960 = 40564819207271943466751741330072
```

---

**Using geng and listg**

Both of these programs are among many others are included in the `nauty and Traces` download link on the [home page](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/). ([User's guide](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/Guide.html))

The programs are written in `C` and make use of `make` and can run on Linux. Instead of using Cygwin on Windows, [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) can be [installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) instead.

The source code can be downloaded using

```
wget "http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/nauty26r11.tar.gz"
```

then

```
tar xvzf nauty26r11.tar.gz
cd nauty26r11
./configure
make
```

[nauty](https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-geng) generates output in [graph6 format](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html) by default but can be converted to list of edges using [listg](https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-listg), e.g.

```
eric@WINDOWS-XYZ:~/nauty26r11$ ./geng 3 | ./listg -e
>A ./geng -d0D2 n=3 e=0-3
>Z 4 graphs generated in 0.00 sec

Graph 1, order 3.
3 0

Graph 2, order 3.
3 1
0 2

Graph 3, order 3.
3 2
0 2  1 2

Graph 4, order 3.
3 3
0 1  0 2  1 2
```

Useful options for the programs

**geng**

```
-help  : options
 -c    : only write connected graphs    (A001349)
 -u    : do not output any graphs, just generate and count them
```

Example

```
eric@WINDOWS-ABC:~/nauty26r11$ ./geng -c -u 10
>A ./geng -cd1D9 n=10 e=9-45
>Z 11716571 graphs generated in 5.09 sec
```

Notice that `11716571` is the size for `10` from A001349

---

**How to create file on Windows using WSL**

Since WSL can access the Windows file system it is possible to direct the output from WSL commands to a Windows file, e.g.

```
touch /mnt/c/Users/Eric/graphs.txt
```

The touch step is not needed, but I use it to create an empty file first then verify that it is there on Windows to ensure I have typed the path correctly.

Here is an example that creates the graph edge list for A001349 in the users directory.

```
.geng -c 1 | .listg -e >> /mnt/c/Users/Eric/graphs.txt
.geng -c 2 | .listg -e >> /mnt/c/Users/Eric/graphs.txt
```

Comment: Of interest: OEIS - Number of graphs on n labeled nodes - [A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125)

Comment: Of interest: [Combination calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php)

Comment: Of interest: [collections of graphs](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) - Did not need for this specific problem, but nice to know if you are working on graphs.

Comment: Of interest: [nauty and Traces](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) - nauty and Traces are programs for computing automorphism groups of graphs and digraphs. [Note](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml) about NAUTY

Comment: Of interest: [Graph Isomorphism](http://algorist.com/problems/Graph_Isomorphism.html)

Comment: Of iterest: [The Stanford GraphBase](https://github.com/ascherer/sgb) - The Stanford GraphBase (SGB) is a collection of datasets and computer programs that generate and examine a wide variety of graphs and networks.” It was developed and published by Donald E. Knuth in 1993.

Comment: Of interest: The small connected simple graphs [V<=7](https://oeis.org/A000088/a000088_3.pdf) from `Field Guide to Simple Graphs`, Volume 1, Part 3 by Peter Steinbach - This gives images of the graphs.

Comment: Of interest: OEIS - Number of connected graphs with n nodes. - [A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349) - This is the goal.

Comment: Of interest: [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) - Windows Subsystem for Linux [Installation Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) for Windows 10 - Used for downloading, building and running [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) and [geng](https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-geng) in a Linux subsystem on Windows 10. Obviates the need to use Cygwin and it is free.

Comment: Of interest: [graph formats](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html) - specifically `graph6` which is the default output of `geng`.

Comment: Of interest: nauty and Traces User’s Guide (Version 2.6) - [pdf](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/nug26.pdf)  - Link posted here because link on [home page](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) not so obvious. - Worth reading if you don't plan to use the tools as it is good introduction to graph terminology and concepts.

Comment: Of interest: [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/acomip/)

Comment: Of interest: [Three Meta-Interpreters: Prolog in Prolog, EXSHELL, and a Planner](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~luger/ai-final2/CH6_Three%20Meta-Intrepeters%20-%20Prolog%20in%20Prolog,%20EXSHELL,%20and%20a%20Planner.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_3.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Meta-programming](http://www.cs.miami.edu/home/geoff/Courses/CSC749-17F/Content/Prolog/Meta.shtml) - Makes use of  `memoizing` to improve the efficiency of generating Fibonacci numbers. Might work but gives me a sour taste.

Comment: Of interest: [Explaining Prolog Based Expert Systems Using a Layered
Meta-interpreter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b88/5797173d6f806d5edcdef521425668394336.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: Rosetta Code - Prolog - [Fibonacci sequence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Prolog) - Has some interesting solutions that might apply.

Comment: Of interest: Rosetta Code - Prolog [Solve a Hidato puzzle](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Solve_a_Hidato_puzzle#Prolog) - Gave me an idea. Make list ahead of time with variables for all of the graphs and then fill the holes as needed.

Comment: Of interest: Rosetta Code - Prolog - [Knight's tour](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) - Has to generate a move and test all previous positions.

Comment: Of interest: Rosetta Code - Prolog - [Y combinator](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Prolog)

Comment: Of interest: [Accumulating while in recursion/backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12255117/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [Tabled execution (SLG resolution)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling)

Comment: Of interest: [Coroutining using Prolog engines](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=engines)

Comment: Of interest: [library(aggregate):](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) Aggregation operators on backtrackable predicates

Comment: Of interest: [Global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar)

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [Delimited continuations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=delcont) -  The mechanism allows for proper coroutines, two or more routines whose execution is interleaved, while they exchange data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **SWI-Prolog** you can store values in [global vars](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar):

1. backtrackable `b`: `b_setval`, `b_getval`
2. not backtrackable `nb`:  `nb_setval`, `nb_getval`

besides using [dynamic predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dynpreds): `assert/retract`.

```
item(1).
item(1).
item(2).
item(3).
item(1).
item(7).
item(1).
item(4).
```

Solution 1 using regular list

```
gen_test(Item) :-
   nb_setval(sofar, []),
   item(Item),   % generate
   once( 
     ( 
       nb_getval(sofar, SoFar),
       (Item > 1, \+ member(Item, SoFar)), % test custom + on membership in earlier tests
       nb_setval(sofar, [Item | SoFar])
     )
     ;           
     true
   ),
   fail; true.
```

Solution 2 using open list

```
 gen_test1(Item) :-
      (
       item(Item),   % generate
       Item > 1, lookup(Item, SoFar, ItemExists)), 
       ItemExists == true -> fail; true
      ); 
      append(SoFar, [], SoFar ), % stubbing open list
      nb_setval(sofar, Sofar).

 lookup( I, [ I | _ ], true).
 lookup( I, [ _ | L ], false) :-
    var( L ); L == [].
 lookup( I, [ _ | L ] ItemExists ):-
    lookup( I, L, ItemExists ).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Open Lists and Difference Lists](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node180.html)

Comment: @GuyCoder excuse me I've killed all prologs on my computer, so I can do only menthal debugging a little while by now....>>`For gen_test I added a , after (Item > 1, \+ member(Item, SoFar)) to get the code to load with consult/1 but upon running the result was false.` I just guessed what the point; it needs to remove \+ before member/2. it;'s always succeded when openlists used

Comment: @GuyCoder you simply needed **tabling** feature: `table item/1. it should memoize non-duplicated goals`. After each test you need to store results and cleanup table(s). it's near to 1st example with regular (proper) list.

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [Tabled execution (SLG resolution)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling)

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [Delimited continuations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=delcont)